# Why isn't my github project going live?

Tags: github, github-pages, git-bash

[image]I created a subbranch for gh-pages. I don't know why the page isn't getting created. I'm attaching the screen shot of the bash.
Even at the github page, when I hover over the tick mark, it says that github has successfully created the page.
[Link to my github](https://github.com/puneeth8994/portfolio/branches)

[image]

Comment: if you want to create a github page you need to call it properly https://pages.github.com/

Comment: The screen shot shows a push for "gh-branches"; your github shows "gh-branches" as published: https://github.com/puneeth8994/portfolio/tree/gh-pages - you've created a branch, published it to github, what else did you want to accomplish?

Comment: If you follow the link to https://puneeth8994.github.io/portfolio/ in your settings, you can see that your site is published. Where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a github pages site, you must follow the naming convention for your repository; in your case `puneeth8994.github.io`.

Also, the main html file should be called *index.html*.

The following is a great resource to get started on github pages:

https://24ways.org/2013/get-started-with-github-pages/